# How does a free rigid body rotate after being launched by an arm moving in a circular motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say some rigid object is held by an arm (of length 1m, for argument's sake). The arm is rotating at a fixed rate w around its pivot point at the bottom. So, while the object is held by the arm, it is rotating at rate w around the pivot point of the arm, which is ~1m away from its centre of mass.

Then, at some point the arm releases the object. It will start moving in a direction given by the tangent of the arm's movement at the moment of release.

But what about its rotational movement? At the instant before release, it's rotating (due to forces applied by the arm) around a point ~1m from its centre of mass. When it is released, it becomes a free body, and therefore can only rotate about its own centre of mass? Right or wrong? How does the rotation around a point 1m away translate into rotation around the centre of mass? Or does the released object not rotate at all?

Comment: I read that thread just before asking my own question! If it does answer my question, I was not able to figure out the answer from reading it.

Comment: OK. In that case, are you familiar with the centripetal force?

Comment: Yes... but there is no such force acting once the object has been released by the arm, right?

Comment: Yes there is. All the particles of the rigid rotate about some point experience a centripetal force towards the center of rotation. But all those forces are internal to the system of particles

Comment: We are talking about the body as a whole, and these forces all cancel each other out. Do you know the answer to my question, and are trying to lead me there through questioning?

Comment: Yes, but they will only cancel out if the center of rotation is the center of mass. That's the point.

Comment: So... what happens when the object is released? Does it rotate? If so, how does it rotate, and about what axis does it rotate?

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: Free body don't rotate, it's some force that cause rotation. A body like pebble not rotate after releasing from rotation but some disk or ball only rotate if torque is applied.

Comment: So when the object is released from the rotating arm, it does not rotate any more?

Answer (score 1):

> So, while the object is held by the arm, it is rotating at rate w around the pivot point of the arm, which is ~1m away from its centre of mass.

This is called the "instant center of rotation".  It can be useful in some situations, and less useful in others.  It is also frame-dependent.  (In this particular case, I don't think it's useful).

Other times, you might prefer to decompose the motion into a rotation about the center of mass and a translation/acceleration of the center of mass.  When you do that, the rotation remains constant unless there's a torque applied.

> When it is released, it becomes a free body, and therefore can only rotate about its own centre of mass?

If you're asking about the instant center of rotation, no.  This is frame dependent.  It might (instantaneously) be appearing to rotate around a point outside itself.  But that may be unimportant.

Both before and after the release, the object would have some rotational speed, and that speed does not change upon release.  The location of the center of this rotation doesn't help you here, so best to ignore it.

> How does the rotation around a point 1m away translate into rotation around the centre of mass?

The instant center of rotation isn't a physical object, so it changes depending on the reference frame and motion of the object.

You're incorrect that the center of rotation immediately moves to coincide with the center of mass.  That's only true in the frame where the center of mass is at rest.

Comment: "Both before and after the release, the object would have some rotational speed, and that speed does not change upon release. The location of the center of this rotation doesn't help you here, so best to ignore it." 

Sorry, this confuses . If it's rotating, it's rotating around an axis. Where is that axis? Why is it unimportant?

Comment: Imagine a wheel rolling on the ground past you.  The instant center of rotation is the contact point on the ground.  Is that point important in understanding the rotation?  Is it more important than the axle?    If you change to the car's frame, the instant center of rotation is now the axle.    

Just because there is an instant center of rotation doesn't necessarily mean that it makes sense to say "the object is rotating around that point".

Comment: OK, but what actually happens when it's released? How does it rotate and move? If the arm is rotating at a rate w, does the ball rotate at that same rate upon release?

Comment: Yes.  The object was rotating at that rate before release and continues to do so after the release.

Answer (score 0):

> When it is released, it becomes a free body, and therefore can only
> rotate about its own centre of mass? Right or wrong?

Right, it can only rotate about its center of mass.  But it is not quite a free body. There is still the force of gravity acting on it.

Before the body is released, it is subjected to two forces, gravity and the force exerted by the persons arm. However, once the rigid body is released, the only external force acting on the body is gravity. It acts on the center of mass (COM) of the body and therefore produces no net torque about the COM.  Under these conditions the rigid body, if rotating upon release, will continue to rotate with constant angular velocity but its center of rotation (COR) will transition to the COM. There is a YouTube video out there showing this when a person releases a rod (unfortunately, I can't recall where it is.)

For simplicity, let the rigid body consist of two equal masses $M$ connected by a bar whose mass is negligible compared $M$. See FIG 1 below. FIG 2 shows the rigid body rotating about its COM. FIG 3 shows the rigid body with the COR being other than the COM.

In both FIG 2 and 3 the masses are rotating with a constant angular velocity $\omega$ about the COR. Therefore each mass experiences a centripetal force $F_C$ about its COR of

$$F_{C}=Mr\omega ^2$$

where $r$ is the distance between each mass and its COR.

Note that in FIG 2, where the COR is the COM, the two masses are equidistant from the COR. Thus the centripetal forces acting on each mass are equal and opposite, for a net force along the bar of zero. Note that the magnitude of the centripetal force is the tension in the bar.

However, in FIG 3 where the COR is not equidistant between the two masses, the centripetal forces acting on masses are not equal for a net force along the bar ($F_C$ on one mass is three times the other). But for this to be the case, it would require a net external force acting along the bar resulting in translation of the COM along that direction. Since no such external force is being applied, the COR needs to be the same as the COM.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I think I'm still very confused abou this. The situation you are showing in fig3, you say "Since no such external force is being applied, the COR needs to be the same as the COM." So does that mean Fig3 is a physical impossibility?

What I dont understand is this bit "its center of rotation (COR) will transition to the COM.". This transition - how long does it take, and how does the object rotate and behave during this period?

Comment: Yes it means FIG 3 is a physical impossibility. My point was to show that the COR can't be other than the COM by contradiction. Insofar as how long it takes to transition to the COM and how it behaves during the transition, you know that the change in rotation can't occur instantaneously upon release, but exactly how and when requires more thought.  But I think that question expands the scope of your original question and perhaps should be a new post.  I think I've answered the scope of your original  question.

Comment: I wrote in my original question "How does the rotation around a point 1m away translate into rotation around the centre of mass?" :)

If it's the case that the COR has to be the COM, yet the transition cannot be instant, then there must be a period in which the free object's COR is not the COM right? But this is a contradiction?

Comment: @TomDavies Sorry, I didn’t interpret word “translate” as meaning the same thing as the word “transition”.

Comment: @TomDavies In any event, before getting into a discussion of the transition, do you or do you not agree that FIG 3  and the related analysis demonstrates the COR cannot be other than the COM, irrespective of the  question of how it transitions?

Answer (score 0):

After the body is released, neglecting aerodynamic forces, the only external force acting on the system is its weight. From Netwon's second law of dynamics,

$\dfrac{d\mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \mathbf{R}^{ext}$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$$m \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_G = m \mathbf{g}$

the center of mass $G$ of the body describes a parabolic trajectory, while the object rotates around it, with constant angular momentum $ \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_G = \mathbb{I}_G \cdot \boldsymbol {\omega}$, since

$\dfrac{d \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_G}{dt} = \mathbf{M}^{ext}_G = \mathbf{0}$.

Being a rigid body, the velocity of a material point $P$ of the body reads

$\mathbf{v}_P = \mathbf{v}_G + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_G)$